# Which is correct? Understanding the term マシ

Tags: translation, word-choice, nuances

少しはマシになってきたな - it's getting a bit better.

I asked someone and they told me I wrote " You're looking a bit better"

Comment: What's the context? *What* is getting better?

Answer (score 2):

> 少しはマシになってきたな
>
> - It's getting a bit better.
> - You're looking a bit better.

Both are correct.
According to [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/): Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese, マシ is used far more for expressing the state of things, but it is also used for people.
In the case of a person, it usually refers to that the person's health condition is getting better.

**For things**

- １週間でもう白く水が濁り始めていました。まぁ、これで濁りは**マシになる**と思います。最後に水質向上剤。
- ヘルメットの風切り音でしたら、空気穴を閉めれば**マシになる**と思います。
- ＳＭＡＰの中居って最近前より歌が**マシになった**って思うのは気のせいですか？
- 日本の景気は、来年は少しは**マシになる**でしょうか？
- 夏休みですから混んでると思います。御盆休みよりは**マシになる**かもしれません。

**For people**

- とりあえず、薬飲んで寝ます。明日には少し**マシになってる**といいんだが。
- 食べたらダメでしたので、給食でお団子やお餅が出たら、残してました。その次の日には**マシになって**遅いものの食べれてました。
- 背中にお肉が乗っかって首が埋もれてた。今は大分**マシになり**、鎖骨もその存在が分かるまでになった。こうなると二度と太りたくなくなる。
- 少しでもキレイになろうと思って、洗顔や食べ物などにも気をつかい前よりはだいぶ**マシになり**ました。

---

## EDIT

誰{だれ}かの顔｛かお｝のニキビが治｛なお｝ってきたとき、その人｛ひと｝に対｛たい｝して、「少しはマシになってきたな」と言｛い｝いますが、日本語｛にほんご｝では次｛つぎ｝のように、いずれの方法｛ほうほう｝でも表現｛ひょうげん｝できます。

- 「お前のニキビが少しはマシになってきたな」
- 「ニキビが治って、お前少しはマシになってきたな」

同様｛どうよう｝に、英語｛えいご｝でも「ニキビ」に着目｛ちゃくもく｝した場合｛ばあい｝と、「ニキビの持｛も｝ち主｛ぬし｝」に着目｛ちゃくもく｝した場合｛ばあい｝とで二通｛ふたとお｝りの表現｛ひょうげん｝ができると思｛おも｝います。

When someone's acne in the face is getting better, we say to him/her "少しはマシになってきたな".
We can express the phrase in the following both ways like:

- "お前のニキビが少しはマシになってきたな".
- "ニキビが治って、お前少しはマシになってきたな".

Naturally I think that you can express the situation in two ways in English: when paying attention to 'acne itself' or 'acne's owner'.

- "It's getting a bit better."
- "Your acne has somewhat healed, so you are looking a bit better."